# Spring On Submit Button textbox value keep unchanged but select tag getting empty

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

This is my PojoClass

```
package com.LoginPojo;

    import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

    public class LoginDeatils {
    public String state;

    public String district;

    public String userName;



    public String getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public void setDistrict(String district) {
        this.district = district;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }



    }
```

This is my JSP File :-

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
            <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form:form action="login" method="POST" commandName="loginBean" accept-charset="UTF-8">  
        <table> 
        <tr>
            <td>Name:<form:input id="userName" name="userName" path="userName" /><br></td>
             <td align="left"><form:errors path="userName" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>State: <form:select path="state" items="${stateList}" onchange="addDistrictValues()"  /><br></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>District: <form:select path="district"    /><br></td>

            </tr>

        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="login"/>

    </form:form>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function addDistrictValues() {
                 document.getElementById("userName").value="abchd";    

                 var x = document.getElementById("district");
                 var option = document.createElement("option");
                 option.text = "Raigad";
                 x.add(option); 


            }
            </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my Controller:

```
package com.SelectTagPackage;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.validation.Valid;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    import com.LoginPojo.LoginDeatils;
    import com.validator.LoginValidator;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public class SelectTagController {

        @Autowired
        LoginValidator loginValidator;

        public LoginValidator getLoginValidator() {
            return loginValidator;
        }

        public void setLoginValidator(LoginValidator loginValidator) {
            this.loginValidator = loginValidator;
        }

        @RequestMapping (method =  RequestMethod.POST)
         public ModelAndView loginPOST(@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginBean")LoginDeatils loginBean , BindingResult bindingResult,ModelMap map) throws Exception 
         {  
            loginValidator.validate(loginBean, bindingResult);
             if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {           
                 return  new ModelAndView("pageForSelectTag"); //JSP Page Name
                }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("bindingResult.hasErrors() else block");
           return  new ModelAndView("pageForSelectTag"); //JSP Page Name
             }
         }

        @RequestMapping (method =  RequestMethod.GET)
         public ModelAndView loginGET(@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginBean")LoginDeatils loginBean , BindingResult bindingResult,ModelMap map) throws Exception 
         {


           return  new ModelAndView("pageForSelectTag");
         }


        @ModelAttribute("stateList")
        public List loadprofessionList() {
             List<String> stateList = new ArrayList<String>();
             stateList.add("Maharashtra");
             stateList.add("Keral");

              return stateList;
        }

    }
```

This is my Validator Class :-

```
package com.validator;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
    import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
    import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

    import com.LoginPojo.LoginDeatils;



    @Component
    public class LoginValidator   implements Validator {

        public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return LoginDeatils.class.isAssignableFrom(arg0);
        }

        public void validate(Object arg0, Errors errors) {

            LoginDeatils objLoginDeatils=(LoginDeatils)arg0;

            if(!objLoginDeatils.getUserName().equals("milind"))
            {           
                 ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "userName", "error.userName", "userName is requiredddd.");

            }

        }

    }
```

My Issue is :- whenever i am executing onchange event of state combo box 2 things happen

```
<td>State: <form:select path="state" items="${stateList}" onchange="addDistrictValues()"  /><br></td>
```

1) addDistrictValues javascript method is getting called.

```
function addDistrictValues() {
             document.getElementById("userName").value="abchd";    

             var x = document.getElementById("district");
             var option = document.createElement("option");
             option.text = "Raigad";
             x.add(option); 


        }
```

setting abchd value to userName text box refer :-

```
document.getElementById("userName").value="abchd";
```

and 2nd Raigad value will get added into district select box JSP Code :-

```
<td>District: <form:select path="district"    /><br></td>
```

javascript code :-

```
var x = document.getElementById("district");
             var option = document.createElement("option");
             option.text = "Raigad";
             x.add(option);
```

but whenever i click on submit button i. e

```
<input type="submit" value="login"/>
```

controller loginPOST method getting called which internally calls validate method and form get loaded again

```
@RequestMapping (method =  RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView loginPOST(@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginBean")LoginDeatils loginBean , BindingResult bindingResult,ModelMap map) throws Exception 
     {  
        loginValidator.validate(loginBean, bindingResult);
         if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {           
             return  new ModelAndView("pageForSelectTag"); //JSP Page Name
            }
         else
         {
             System.out.println("bindingResult.hasErrors() else block");
       return  new ModelAndView("pageForSelectTag"); //JSP Page Name
         }
     }
```

but when controller method with validate method calls textbox value "abchd" remains as it is on textbox but "Raigad" value which we have added through javascript[textbox value also set by javascript] will get vanish from select box

```
so why only select box value only getting vanish but textbox value remains unchange , both are setting by javascript.

plz help
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L17o4.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78WND.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znxTX.jpg)

i searched more in google but i am not getting any proper solution from any where

but when controller method with validate method calls textbox value "abchd" remains as it is on textbox but "Raigad" value which we have added through javascript[textbox value also set by javascript] will get vanish from select box

so why IN SPRING only select box value only getting vanish but textbox value remains unchange , both are setting by javascript.

Once u see the attached images ur doubt will gets clear

plz help

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing a list of items for the "district" select control like what you are doing for the "state" select control. Try this in your Controller:

```
    @ModelAttribute("districtMap")
    public List loadDistrictMap() {
         Map<String, String> districts new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
         districts.put("1", "1st District");
         districts.put("2", "2nd District");
         districts.put("3", "Raigad");
         districts.put("n", "Nth District");

          return districts;
    }
```

And then in your JSP form:

```
<td>District: <form:select path="district" items="${districtMap}"    /><br></td>
```

The district map is just an example list, it could come from a database or something but the point is that your controller should somehow provide the full list of possible districts options so that the select control can bind the correct one based on the "path" attribute.

Comment: Thanks for ur response but actually my requirement is that i want to change district value based upon selection of state value if i go with ur above shared code then district values will remains same for any state which i dont want.

Comment: my json code is ready but whenever i am getting response from ajax json call and i am adding same response in my district combo box that time it addded successfully but when i click on submit button that time dynamically added json response get vanished  plz help